# Using print statements only to debug

Tags: python

I have been coding a lot in Python of late. And I have been working with data that I haven't worked with before, using formulae never seen before and dealing with huge files.  All this made me write a lot of print statements to verify if it's all going right and identify the points of failure. But, generally, outputting so much information is not a good practice. How do I use the print statements only when I want to debug and let them be skipped when I don't want them to be printed?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module has everything you could want. It may seem excessive at first, but only use the parts you need. I'd recommend using [`logging.basicConfig`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) to toggle the logging level to `stderr` and the [simple log methods](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.debug), `debug`, `info`, `warning`, `error` and `critical`.

```
import logging, sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('A debug message!')
logging.info('We processed %d records', len(processed_records))
```

Comment: Also, in case you had trouble installing this module like me; logging is part of the standard library - no need for pip install even when using a virtual environment

Comment: How does one set the level of the logging such that it only prints errors and not debug messages?

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli set `level`, in the `basicConfig` call, to `logging.ERROR`.

Comment: I am afraid this does not work on jupyter lab 1.2.6. You can set the logging level once, and re-setting is using `logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.ERROR)` will have no effect. Restarting the kernel and setting the new level works, but that's a workaround for me.

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli you should ask another question for this. But likely you'll need to directly change the level on the root logger, jupyter is probably calling basicConfig before you.

Comment: @MattJoiner Correct, use `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)` in Jupyter

Answer (score 45):

A simple way to do this is to call a logging function:

```
DEBUG = True

def log(s):
    if DEBUG:
        print s

log("hello world")
```

Then you can change the value of `DEBUG` and run your code with or without logging.

The standard [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module has a more elaborate mechanism for this.

Comment: It's probably better in the long run to use the supplied [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module than roll your own (even though it looks more complicated).

Comment: True, but it's worthwhile understanding how one *could* roll their own.

Comment: Indeed. The above is a good idea of how `logging` works (at a very simple level).

Comment: This is the one that I use for my aws lambdas.

Comment: I would replace `s` with `*s` so you can pass comma delimited values like in `print()` function.

Answer (score 22):

Use the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) built-in library module instead of printing.

You create a `Logger` object (say `logger`), and then after that, whenever you insert a debug print, you just put:

```
logger.debug("Some string")
```

You can use `logger.setLevel` at the start of the program to set the output level. If you set it to DEBUG, it will print all the debugs. Set it to INFO or higher and immediately all of the debugs will disappear.

You can also use it to log more serious things, at different levels (INFO, WARNING and ERROR).

Answer (score 15):

First off, I will second the nomination of python's [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) framework.  Be a little careful about how you use it, however.  Specifically: let the logging framework expand your variables, don't do it yourself.  For instance, instead of:

```
logging.debug("datastructure: %r" % complex_dict_structure)
```

make sure you do:

```
logging.debug("datastructure: %r", complex_dict_structure)
```

because while they look similar, the first version incurs the repr() cost *even if it's disabled*.  The second version avoid this.  Similarly, if you roll your own, I'd suggest something like:

```
def debug_stdout(sfunc):
    print(sfunc())

debug = debug_stdout
```

called via:

```
debug(lambda: "datastructure: %r" % complex_dict_structure)
```

which will, again, avoid the overhead if you disable it by doing:

```
def debug_noop(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

debug = debug_noop
```

The overhead of computing those strings probably doesn't matter unless they're either 1) expensive to compute or 2) the debug statement is in the middle of, say, an n^3 loop or something.  Not that I would know anything about that.

Comment: There's more information on this important topic under 'optimisation' in the logging howto: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#optimization

Comment: `Because while they look similar, the first version incurs the repr() cost even if it's disabled. The second version avoid this.` - As dummy I ask myself, where is this documented? What is a *repr() cost*?

Comment: It's not documented, it's implicit: doing `foo("%r" % bar)` "obviously" executes the interpolation (% operator) before passing the result to `foo`. Hence, even if `foo()` does nothing with the result, the computational cost of doing the interpolation is still incurred.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about others, but I was used to define a *"global constant"* (`DEBUG`) and then a global function (`debug(msg)`) that would print `msg` only if `DEBUG == True`.

Then I write my debug statements like:

```
debug('My value: %d' % value)
```

...then I pick up **unit testing** and never did this again! :)

Comment: Unit testing ha. Okay, thats another thing to be picked up then :(

Comment: I don't want to discourage unit testing -- it is essential. But I don't think it's a substitute for logging, even as a debugging technique. I still do a lot of printing to quickly test things.

Comment: @crazyaboutliv - Unit testing done properly is great. Have a look to [this chapter](http://diveintopython.org/unit_testing/index.html) of diving into python for a snappy, concise, easy-to-follow presentation

Comment: @mgiuca - I do quick printing too, but it's just a couple or so of `print()` while bringing up my code to the required level to pass the test. I never end up with huge amount of `print()` all over the place. Logging is cool too! :)

Comment: I am ending up with too many of them.  And later, I am importing methods from that program to another one and it ends up printing a lot of junk that is not required. So,  thats why i need to use something :)

Comment: @mac It looks like your link now requires an explicit 'www' - it is now [hosted here](http://www.diveintopython.net/unit_testing/index.html).

Comment: @culix - Thank you for the comment. Alas, it is not possible to edit comments after a few minutes one enters them into the system... I upvoted your comment hoping it will be more visible. BTW: the link is broken because the author of "Dive into Python", Mark Pilgrim, [committed infosuicide a while back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Pilgrim_%28software_developer%29#.22Disappearance.22_from_the_Internet).

Answer (score 1):

A better way to debug the code is, by using module clrprint

It prints a color full output only when pass parameter debug=True

```
from clrprint import *
clrprint('ERROR:', information,clr=['r','y'], debug=True)
```