# Enabling and disabling debug messages in Python

Tags: python, debugging, nonetype

I'm currently learning Python and to be aware of what's going on behind the scenes I write a lot of printouts. 
Seeing as it's quite a fuss to go back and comment all the messages I've started writing a module where I set all the messages in the method I want to use them and then use a boolean to turn the messages off and on.
Problem is, I get None printouts instead of my debug messages which isn't very elegant. Any way to get around this?

Some sample code:

```
def setDebug(bool):
    '''
    Toggles the debug messages
    '''

    global _debug
    _debug = bool


def setNewMsg(msg):
    '''
    Appends a new debug message to the list
    '''
    global _debugMsg
    _debugMsg.append(msg)

def getDebugMsg(index):
    '''
    Takes an int for a parameter and returns the debug message needed
    '''
    global _debug
    global _debugMsg

    if _debug == True:
        return _debugMsg[index] 
    else: 
        return
```

Comment: Are you aware that you're getting `None` because you're returning `None` if `_debug` is `False`?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't name variables as `bool`, since you will be overriding the built-in function `bool`.

Comment: Absolutely, so how do I return _nothing_ as opposed to None?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579496/using-print-statements-only-to-debug-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you said you're new to Python, I think you should consider using the `logging` module

Look at this [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), also the [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) can really help.

from the Python docs:

```
This module defines functions and classes which implement a flexible event logging system for applications and libraries.
```

You can set the logging module to save all your prints to file and by controlling the logging level you can control the level of messaged.

Example:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='mylog.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

If `level=logging.DEBUG` you'll be able to see all messages but by changing to `level=logging.INFO` it will save to the file only info and above. try the links they are very useful.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll read up on the logging utilities once I get a little further ahead with my coding. Right now I'm just writing simple examples for a MOOC. The online testing algorithms are very picky about what gets printed out and I was looking for a quick way of simply turning the logging off. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You're getting `None` since you're returning it if your `_debug` variable is false.

If the `_debug` is false, you can return an empty string:

```
return ''
```

Or you might want to return a message:

```
return 'Debug mode is not set to True'
```

Returning *nothing* is basically the same as returning `None`. Even if you don't return anything, Python will set the returned value as `None`:

```
>>> def test():
    pass

>>> a = test()
>>> print a
None
```

Also, if you want to use your method instead of the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module, you might want to check if `_debugMsg[index]` exists.

```
if _debug:
    try:
       return _debugMsg[index]
    except IndexError:
       return 'The debug message hasn't listed yet.'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help! My problem was that I don't want anything to print out. See above. Cheers